# Why can't I use bigints with typescript when targetting esNext?

Tags: typescript, tsconfig, bigint

This is my typescript configuration

```
$ npx tsc --showConfig
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "es2021",
        "lib": [],
        "module": "commonjs",
        "esModuleInterop": true,
        "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
        "strict": true,
        "skipLibCheck": true
    },
    "files": [
        "./index.ts",        ]
}
```

And this is my `index.ts`:

```
const a = 1n;
```

When I try to run `tsc` I get this output

```
$ npx tsc index.ts
error TS2737: BigInt literals are not available when targeting lower than ES2020.
```

Why am I getting this error? Is there anything wrong with my tsconfig file?

Comment: What typescript version are you using? It might not know about ES2021.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you run `tsc` with a filename as argument, then `tsconfig.json` will be ignored.

Either use the `--target` argument, or run `tsc` *without* `index.ts`