# Getting error exponentiation operator for BigInt

Tags: javascript, typescript, bigint

When i am trying to do

```
(BigInt(Generator) ** this.privateKey) % BigInt(Prime)
```

i am getting error: Exponentiation cannot be performed on 'bigint' values unless the 'target' option is set to 'es2016' or later.

my tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es2020",                               
    "lib": ["es2020", "esnext", "dom"],                                       

    /* Modules */
    "module": "commonjs",                               
   "types": ["./node_modules/user-agent-data-types", "node"],
    "esModuleInterop": true,                          
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,          

    /* Type Checking */
    "strict": true,                                     

    /* Completeness */
    "skipLibCheck": true                                
  }
}
```

changing target to esnext changes nothing

Comment: obviously the build system is not using your `tsconfig.json` file - what happens if you set the target to `es2016` - exactly the minimum viable value

Comment: @Bravo can you help me to fix this pls? i use tsc folder/tsfile.ts to build. My tsconfig.json placed in root

Comment: not sure I can help - no clue how your build system is set up, and there are as many ways to set up as there are stars in the sky - so, you'll need to do some more debugging since it's your set up

Comment: I would suggest looking at the error itself - is there more to it that you didn't post?

Comment: @Bravo my full error log: https://pastebin.com/9YR94Uck

Comment: So, that's not even the FIRST error - why did you ignore the first three errors regarding BigInt? all the errors mention the `dh` folder - is this a folder in your project? Perhaps you need to set the target correctly in some file in that folder? I have no clue what's in that folder, so, I can only guess

Comment: @Bravo i ignore them because they do not interfere me build js files. Only after i added exponentation i got problem with building. How can i set target for files in that folder correctly?(sorry, i am new to ts) I initialized tsconfig.json only in root of my project and did not pointed any folders, files. dh is my only folder in project with ts files

Comment: no clue because I don't know what that folder is or what's in it that could possibly be overriding the complerOptions.target from the config you've shown

Comment: @Bravo i pushed it to github: https://github.com/Oringik/crypto-chateau-js

Comment: good - how do you compile/build?

Comment: @Bravo just ```tsc dh/dh.ts```

Comment: See this duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68976870/why-cant-i-use-bigints-with-typescript-when-targetting-esnext - then you'll have other errors, because apparently `BigInt(someVariableThatIsAlreadyBigInt)` is not allowed

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why can't I use bigints with typescript when targetting esNext?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68976870/why-cant-i-use-bigints-with-typescript-when-targetting-esnext)

Comment: @Bravo no, getting the same error when building only with ```tsc``` or ```tsc --target dh/dh.ts```

Comment: right ... so you think `--target` is enough - how do you think `--target` tells the compiler what the target is? try `--target es2020` - then you'll see all the other errors you've made in your code

Comment: @Bravo oh.. sorry. Now it is working. Thank you very much!